# Pagination for ajax category filter

Tags: categories, filters, ajax, pagination

I created an AJAX category filter for a custom post type with custom taxonomy.

1)It's working but can't figure out how to add pagination for the custom taxonomy once it filters. When I click on pagination link 2 or 3 it takes to http://website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=3

2) Can't figure out how to load ALL categories on page load

Here's my code so far:

Thanks

Custom.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//AJAX filter
    function cat_ajax_get(catID) {
        jQuery("a.ajax").removeClass("current");
        jQuery("a.ajax").addClass("current"); //adds class current to the category menu item being displayed so you can style it with css
        jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ?>";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "load-filter2", cat: catID },
            success: function(response) {
                jQuery("#category-post-content").html(response);
                jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter2', 'prefix_load_term_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter2', 'prefix_load_term_posts' );
function prefix_load_term_posts () {


            $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
                  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array( 
                              'tax_query' => array(
                                       array(
                                          'taxonomy' => 'customtaxonomy',
                                          'field' => 'term_id',
                                          'terms' => array( $cat_id )
                                       )
                                  ),
                              'post_type' => 'customPostType', 
                              'posts_per_page' => 5, 
                              'paged' => $paged
                              );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

               while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div>
                <h3>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h3>
           </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
            <nav class="pagination">
                <?php
                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                            echo paginate_links( array(
                          'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                          'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                          'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                           //'show_all'           => true,
                          //'total'              => 2,
                          'end_size'           => 1,
                          'prev_next'          => True,
                          'prev_text'          => __('< Previous'),
                          'next_text'          => __('Next >'),
                          'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
                      ) );
                  ?>
            </nav>
```

feed-page.php

```
<?php
$args = array(
          'hierarchical' => true,
          'taxonomy' => 'customtaxonomy'
          );
$categories = get_categories($args);?>

<div>

    <?php foreach ( $categories as $cat ) { ?>

        <div id="cat-<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><a class="<?php echo    $cat->slug; ?> ajax btn onclick="cat_ajax_get('<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>');" href="#"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></div>

<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: the page you make an ajax request from and the ajax request itself are two entirely separate requests- you can't get the value of the `paged` query var or use `get_pagenum_link` in the ajax request, you need to pass all required data with the ajax request, like you are doing with `$cat_id`.

Comment: OK I see - thanks for the response. Can you provide a simple example of this?

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to use the paginate_links() see the details in the answer for this question.

[WordPress Pagination not working with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150653/wordpress-pagination-not-working-with-ajax)

kindly,

Comment: Can I have an explanation why it's down voted?